# Fast way to apply a function on each pixel of a PIL Image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I need to apply a function to each pixel in **large** `PIL` Images. I found similar questions here, but somehow the answers never worked for me (mostly, because they were specific to the function).

Going through every pixel with two for-loops works, but is insanely slow. So I thought, there may be a faster way like `numpy.apply_along_axis` or vectorization. However, the first one is slow, too, and I cannot get the second one to work. I appreciate any suggestions!

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# example functions to be applied on each pixel RGB value
# (lets just imagine for now, that l and r cannot be 0)
def blueness(rgb):
    r, g, b = int(rgb[0]), int(rgb[1]), int(rgb[2])
    l = (r+g+b)/3
    return (b/r)*(1/l)*100

input_path = 'input.png'
img = Image.open(input_path)
img_np = np.asarray(orig_img)
h, w, z = img_np.shape
converted_img = np.zeros((h, w))

# apply blueness on img_np
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        converted_img[y, x] = blueness(img_np[y, x])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you have probably already gone wrong if you think about converting images to lists and using `for` loops in Python. You really need to be vectorising with Numpy or Numba or `numexpr` or somesuch.

Here is a way to do that on your function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

def loopy(na):
    # Create output image in greyscale
    res = np.zeros_like(na[..., 0])

    # apply blueness on na
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            res[y, x] = blueness(na[y, x])

    return res

def blueness(rgb):
    r, g, b = int(rgb[0]), int(rgb[1]), int(rgb[2])
    l = (r+g+b)/3
    return (b/r)*(1/l)*100

def me(na):
    # Take mean of RGB values
    l = np.mean(na, axis=2)
    res = (na[..., 2] / na[..., 0]) * 100/l
    return res.astype(np.uint8)

# Guess the height and width
h, w = 1080, 1920

# Create a random image in Numpy array
na = np.random.randint(1,256, (h,w,3), np.uint8)

# Double for loop method
res1 = loopy(na)

# Numpy method
res2 = me(na)
```

---

Here are the results. Numpy is around 65x faster:

```
%timeit me(na)
37 ms ± 523 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit loopy(na)
2.36 s ± 11.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I knew that those `for` loops are bad, and that `vectorization` is the way to go, but I could not come up with how exactly to do it. I think, this will help me for the future as well.

Comment: I can see how using vectorized functions for calculations using the rgb values would work to give a significant speed up (e.g. the blueness or mean examples you gave), but what if the function needed to know the x,y of the current pixel, or the rgb of neighbouring pixels?

Comment: @rwired With some experience, it is amazing what can be vectorised. Try looking at answers by Quang Hoang  https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang and Jérôme Richard https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/jérôme-richard  for examples. In the rare cases where it cannot be vectorised, try looking for answers using `[numba]` in the StackOverflow search box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 
from pathlib import Path

def blueness(*rgb):
    r, g, b = int(rgb[0]), int(rgb[1]), int(rgb[2])
    l = (r+g+b)/3
    return (b/r)*(1/l)*100

def test():
    fname = Path().absolute() / "test.jpg"
    pil_img = Image.open(fname)
    print(pil_img.size)
    img = np.array(pil_img)
    print(img.shape)
    result = [blueness(r,g,b) for r,g,b in zip(np.nditer(img[...,0]), np.nditer(img[...,1]), np.nditer(img[...,2]))]
    print(len(result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

`np.nditer(img[...,0])` will give you all the red values, `np.nditer(img[...,1])` will give all the green values and `np.nditer(img[...,2])` will give all the blue values.

But do cross check your blueness function, for divide by zero case.
It is possible that r,g,b values be zero and then that `1/l` term will infinity.